# OpenCv Mat initialization from array not working

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am initializing a Mat object with an array like this

```
int data[4] = {111,2,3,4};
Mat A = Mat(2, 2, CV_8UC1, data);
```

Now when I am printing the value at (1,1) which should be 4

```
cout<<"\n m1 at 1,1 "<<(int)A.at<uchar>(1,1);
```

it is printing- 0

I am using VS2008 in Windows XP and OpenCv 2.3. I am stuck on it since yesterday.

Comment: Did you try creating data as `unsigned char data[4]`?

Comment: I don't think the value as 1,1 should be 4. It should be something 8*3 bits from the beginning. Your matrix is holding 8 bit elements.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. Can you please explain what is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your matrix holds 8 bit elements (that is what `CV_8UC1` means). You are passing it an array of ints. Assuming 32 bit ints, the first one, `111`, should be enough to fill the array. The most significant 8 bits of `111` would go into position `1,1`, and these are `0`s. So you get an element with value `0`.

Try passing 8 bit unsigned elements:

```
unsigned char data[4] = {111,2,3,4};
Mat A = Mat(2, 2, CV_8UC1, data);
```

Alternatively, if you need to store signed `32` bit elements, use `CV_32S`.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
unsigned char data[4] = {111,2,3,4};
Mat A = Mat(2, 2, CV_8UC1, data);
```

or

```
int data[4] = {111,2,3,4};
Mat A = Mat(2, 2, CV_32SC1, data);
```